# Request Store variable cannot be accessed in delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We are using [request store gem](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store) in our app. It is used for storing global data. But the problem is If I try to access  request store variable in the delayed job It is not accessible. Is there anything extra which needs to be done in order for the request store data to be available in delayed job ?

**Delayed Job Code**

```
class CustomersCreateJob < Struct.new()
  def perform
    puts "Request Data =====> #{RequestStore.store[:current_user] }"
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not available"? The above current_user example hints that you don't understand how Rails and request lifecycle work.

Answer (score 1):

In general, `current_user` by default is only available in controllers for reason.

You did not mention you method or running jobs, but in any way by the time when job starts, even if it happens to be in same process and thread - request is already finished and there's no `current_user`. So pass user's id to job explicitly (this depends on how you run them)

Answer (score 0):

delayed_job workers won't get the request_store normally, because they are outside of the request/response cycle.

However this frequently isn't the desired behaviour, given the typical uses of request_store.

You can always extend `ApplicationJob` yourself with such functionality, (e.g. `around_enqueue` and `around_perform`), and I do recall having to do something similar at a previous role.